# Find the total number of triplets when summed are less than a given threshold

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

So I'm working on some practice problems and having trouble reducing the complexity. I am given an array of distinct integers a[] and a threshold value T. I need to find the number of triplets `i`,`j`,`k` such that `a[i] < a[j] < a[k]` and `a[i] + a[j] + a[k] <= T`. I've gotten this down from `O(n^3)` to `O(n^2 log n)` with the following python script. I'm wondering if I can optimize this any further.

```
import sys
import bisect

first_line = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(' ')
num_numbers = int(first_line[0])
threshold = int(first_line[1])
count = 0

if num_numbers < 3:
    print count
else:
    numbers = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(' ')
    numbers = map(int, numbers)
    numbers.sort()

    for i in xrange(num_numbers - 2):
        for j in xrange(i+1, num_numbers - 1):
            k_1 = threshold - (numbers[i] + numbers[j])
            if k_1 < numbers[j]:
                break
            else:
                cross_thresh = bisect.bisect(numbers,k_1) - (j+1)
                if cross_thresh > 0:
                    count += cross_thresh

    print count
```

In the above example, the first input line simply provides the number of numbers and the threshold. The next line is the full list. If the list is less than 3, there is no triplets that can exist, so we return 0. If not, we read in the full list of integers, sort them, and then process them as follows: we iterate over every element of `i` and `j` (such that i < j) and we compute the highest value of k that would not break `i + j + k <= T`. We then find the index (`s`) of the first element in the list that violates this condition and take all the elements between j and s and add them to the count. For 30,000 elements in a list, this takes about 7 minutes to run. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Instead of performing the binary search on the entire range each time, you know that for each iteration where `j > lastJ`, you only need to search in the range `[0, last_cross_thresh]`.  I'm fairly sure this won't improve either the asymptotic complexity or the runtime in practice much, though.

Comment: Also, you could pre-filter your list by finding the two least elements in the list (in `O(n)` time) and then eliminating any elements from your list such that the sum of the two least elements and that element would exceed `T` (also an `O(n)` scan). That will give you a smaller set to work with, even if your overall algorithm is `O(n^3)` or whatever... Sorting the list beforehand (`O(n lg n)`) might make it even simpler...

Comment: Alternatively you can change the log(n) factor into an additive T term (making this a pseudopolynomial algorithm) by precomputing a size-(T+1) array that records, for each 0 <= i <= T, the number of elements <= i.  This necessitates O(T) space too.

Comment: A slightly stronger variation of @twalberg's idea can be easily incorporated: all you need to do is add an `else <break out of innermost loop>` clause to the end of `if cross_thresh > 0:`.

Answer (score 3):

You are performing binary search for each `(i,j)` pair to find the corresponding value for `k`. Hence `O(n^2 log(n))`.

I can suggest an algorithm that will have the worst case time complexity of `O(n^2)`.

Assume the list is sorted from left to right and elements are numbered from `1` to `n`. Then the pseudo code is:

```
for i = 1 to n - 2:
    j = i + 1
    find maximal k with binary search
    while j < k:
        j = j + 1
        find maximal k with linear search to the left, starting from last k position
```

The reason this has the worst case time complexity of `O(n^2)` and not `O(n^3)` is because the position `k` is monotonically decreasing. Thus even with linear scanning, you are not spending `O(n)` for each `(i,j)` pair. Rather, you are spending a total of `O(n)` time to scan for `k` for each distinct `i` value.

Answer (score 3):

`O(n^2)` version implemented in Python (based on wookie919's answer):

```
def triplets(N, T):
    N = sorted(N)
    result = 0

    for i in xrange(len(N)-2):
        k = len(N)-1
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(N)-1):
            while k>=0 and N[i]+N[j]+N[k]>T:
                k-=1
            result += max(k, j)-j

    return result

import random
sample = random.sample(xrange(1000000), 30000)
print triplets(sample, 500000)
```